# How do I solve this integral in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I am trying to solve this integral in Mathematica
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1} d x e^{iax} K_{0}\left(\sqrt{\left[q x(1-x)+m\right] b}\right) $$
where $a$, $b$, $m$, and $q$ are real positive constants.

I want to solve it in the limit for small argument of $K_0$ i.e.
$K_0(x) \rightarrow -\ln{\frac{x}{2}} +$ finite terms.

So
$$ I=-\int_{0}^{1} d x e^{iax} \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left[q x(1-x)+m\right] b}\right) $$

What I should obtain is this $I\approx\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{4}{mb}}$ but what I obtain is some complex functions. I have tried to use PrincipalValue->True but it doesn't evaluated the integral.
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

---

Edit:
$K_0$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.
I am just using this

```
Integrate[Exp[I*a*x]*Log[Sqrt[(b (m + q (1 - x) x))]/2], {x, 0, 1}]
```

---

Edit:
Say I want to evaluate

```
Integrate[Cos[a*x]*Log[Sqrt[(b (m + q (1 - x) x))]/2], {x, 0, 1}]
```

instead for non-zero $a$, $b$, $m$, and $q$.
Mathematica does not give an answer for this, any help?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: For completeness, what is $K_0$?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve your expected result with `q=0` ?

Comment: No, because I get a complex answer

Comment: Except for special values of `a`, I don't see why the result will have a non-zero imaginary part. E.g., `Block[{a = 1, m = 1, b = 1, q = 1},
 NIntegrate[Exp[I*a*x]*Log[Sqrt[(b (m + q (1 - x) x))]/2], {x, 0, 1}]
 ]`

Answer (score 2):

For the revised integral, if you assume that the parameters are positive rather than just non-zero,

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, m > 0, q > 0},
 int = Integrate[Cos[a*x]*Log[Sqrt[(b (m + q (1 - x) x))]/2], {x, 0, 1}] //
      ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // FullSimplify]

(* (1/(2 a))(Log[(b m)/4] Sin[a] + 
  2 Cos[a/2] ((-CosIntegral[1/2 a (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 m)/q])] + 
        CosIntegral[1/2 a (1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 m)/q])]) Sin[
       1/2 a Sqrt[1 + (4 m)/q]] - 
     Cos[1/2 a Sqrt[
        1 + (4 m)/q]] (SinIntegral[1/2 a (1 + Sqrt[1 + (4 m)/q])] + 
        SinIntegral[1/2 (a - a Sqrt[1 + (4 m)/q])]))) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result for integral I is

```
(I/(2*a))*(1 - E^(I*a))*Log[(b*m)/4] - (1/a)*
E^((I*a)/2)*((-I)*Pi*Sin[(a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])] + 
    (CosIntegral[(a/2)*(1 - Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] - 
   CosIntegral[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])])*
 Sin[(a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])] + 
    (SinIntegral[(a/2)*(1 - Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] + 
   SinIntegral[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])])*
 Cos[(a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])])
```

You can easily workout the real and imaginary parts of this.

Edit: OK, May be not so easy, but the real part is

```
(1/(2*a))*((CosIntegral[(a/2)*(Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q] - 1)] - 
   CosIntegral[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])])*
 Sin[(a/2)*(1 - Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] + 
    (CosIntegral[(-(a/2))*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] - 
   CosIntegral[(a/2)*(1 - Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])])*
 Sin[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] - 
    2*Cos[a/2]*Cos[(a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*
     Sqrt[q])]*(SinIntegral[(a/2)*(1 - Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] + 
   SinIntegral[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])])) + (Sin[a]/a)*
 Log[Sqrt[b*m]/2]
```

and the imaginary part

```
(1/(2*a))*((-Cos[a/2 + (a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])])*
 CosIntegral[-((a*(Sqrt[q] + Sqrt[4*m + q]))/(2*Sqrt[q]))] + 
    Cos[a/2 + (a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])]*
 CosIntegral[a*(1/2 - Sqrt[4*m + q]/(2*Sqrt[q]))] - 
Cos[a/2 - (a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])]*
 CosIntegral[(a/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] + 
    Cos[a/2 - (a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])]*
 CosIntegral[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] + 
4*Cos[a/4]*Cos[(a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])]*Sin[a/4]*
      SinIntegral[(a/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])] - 
4*Cos[a/4]*Cos[(a*Sqrt[4*m + q])/(2*Sqrt[q])]*Sin[a/4]*
 SinIntegral[(a/2)*(1 + Sqrt[4*m + q]/Sqrt[q])]) + (Log[(b*m)/4]*
Sin[a/2]^2)/a
```

A way to calculate these integrals is:
find the derivative of the integrand with respect to q, then integrate it with respect to x as definite integral, and finally find again the antiderivative with respect to q. In the end you have still to determine the integration constant.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints. Since you have that E^I a x term, you only get a real result for a == 0.

Plot the integrand, do numerical integration and compare with expection. It differs.

For q == 0 and a == 0 , you get the expected result, numerical and analytical.

```
Manipulate[{Plot[
  Evaluate@
Through[{Re, 
   Im}[-E^(I a x) Log[1/2 Sqrt[(q x (1 - x) + m) b]]]], {x, 0, 1},
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, ImageSize -> 400], 
  NIntegrate[-E^(I a x) Log[1/2 Sqrt[(q x (1 - x) + m) b]], {x, 0, 
1}], 1./2 Log[4/(m b)]}, {{a, 1}, 0, 4}, {{b, 1}, 0, 5}, {{m, 1}, 
0, 4}, {{q, 1}, 0, 5}]
```